# Angular multiple flex layout with angular material cards

Tags: css, angular, flexbox, angular-material

I wanted to implement the design below with cards using flex layout with the margin but is reponsive , I have tried the stackblitz below but cant seem to figure it out , the margin and layout is either destroyed with tried on other screens or wrong use of flex. Anyone can help me here with the correct implementation of flex layout with example design below ? help is highly appreciated. Thanks.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mat-card-example-flsnue?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.css

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is your working solution

```
<!---HTML--->
<div class="row">
    <div class="leftPannel">
        <mat-card class="card">
            Height will adjust based on content
        </mat-card>
    </div>
    <div class="rightPannel">
        <mat-card class="card">
        </mat-card>
        <mat-card class="card">
        </mat-card>
    </div>
</div>

/* CSS */
.row {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.leftPannel {
  width: 35%;
  margin-right: 20px;
}

.rightPannel {
  flex: 1;
}

.card {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  background-color: #fff;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .row {
    flex-direction: column;
  }
  .leftPannel {
    width: 100%;
    margin-right: 0;
  }
}
```

Comment: how about the margins and height of the card>

Comment: hi @sawan nirala , how to achieve the margin above?

Comment: @TimLaunders top and left-right margin can be managed with the container and height will be based on the content.